# Translating wordpress plugin

Tags: plugins

I built contact form plugin in in wordpress. I am planing to translate field name to diffrent languages. In that cause i will use Poedit. My question is does wordpress has some language options in database, wich could be used. For example when wp is installed you could choose diffrent lang options? So my question how i will trigger translation for my plugin? I read something about constant in wp-config, is there any way to trigger change of language without this constant, cuz i am having separate plugin

Comment: That's out of logic, because I'm using a whole site in `lang=xyz`, and I'm comfortable there, but I want a specific one in `lang=abc` because it's my wish. Isn't that clumsy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the current language of the install with the function `get_locale()`. WordPress save the language in the`options` table, `option_name` is `WPLANG`. But inside the Multisite install is in the table `sitemeta`.

But is not important. You should use the default functions to load a language file inside the theme template or the plugin.

- Theme: `load_theme_textdomain()`
- Plugin: `load_plugin_textdomain()`

You find a small example inside this [contact form template](https://github.com/bueltge/WP-Contact-Form-Template), public.

Comment: may u help me with this http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/168779/translating-wordpress-plugin