# Translating wordpress plugin

Tags: plugins

Ok i built plugin for contact form, I wanna add translation for it. In my main plugin files i add this code

```
function ap_action_init()
{
// Localization
load_plugin_textdomain('prijava_forma', false, dirname(plugin_basename(__FILE__))."/languages");
}

// Add actions
add_action('init', 'ap_action_init');
```

in my file where contact form is written i have this

```
_e('Prva','prijava_forma');
```

In my language folder i added .mo and .po files created with poedit.

Also i defined WPLANG in config.php, and change lang in admin section

But i get no translation. Where could be problem, i am new to this?

Comment: Why do you use an URL to access a local path? That cannot work.

Comment: try already with dirname(plugin_basename(__FILE__))."/languages" not working

Comment: What are the name of the languages files?

Comment: ru.mo and ru are names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I´m using this code to get translated my themes:  
`add_action('after_setup_theme', 'my_theme_setup');
function my_theme_setup(){
    load_theme_textdomain('lc_realty', get_template_directory() . '/languages');
}`

the files are named **ru_RU.mo** and **ru_RU.po** I have no problems with this code on versions 3.3.1 to 3.8.3 I will upgrade to 4.0 soon son I hope this continue working well.

Also I have this code to translate the plugins in admin panel

`if ( is_admin() )
        load_plugin_textdomain( 'myslider', false, 'myslider/languages' );`

 this code goes inside the functions setup of the plugin